# Creating an arc between two points pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, pygame

I am trying to create a smooth curve between two straight lines with known gradients, I have found an equation to find theses two point but when i try to find the angle for each of the points the arc doesn't line up.I have done the math and it (should) be right.

```
def angle(A,B):
    o = abs(B[1]-A[1])
    a = abs(B[0] - A[0])
    angle = math.atan(o/a)
    return angle

a1 = angle((250, 175),(75, 300))
a2 = angle((250, 175),(400, 315))
pygame.draw.arc(gameDisplay, WHITE, (0 ,0 ,500,350), (math.pi) + a2,(2*math.pi) - a1)
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, BLUE, [400,0], [400, 500], 1)
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, BLUE, [0,315], [1000, 315], 1)   
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, RED, [75,0], [75, 500], 1)
pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, RED, [0,300], [1000, 300], 1)
```

This is the basic code for finding the start and stop angle, with (250,175) being the center of the ellipse and (75, 300) and (400, 315) being the two points. The lines are where the arc should start and stop.

Comment: `math.atan` only has a range of pi radians (180 degrees). To get the full 360 degrees, you should use `math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)`. Those additions and subtractions in the `arc` call also look suspicious to me.

Comment: What you draw is an elliptical arc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not draw a perfect circular arc, actually you are drawing an elliptical arc. You've to take into account the rectangular area, which is passed to [`pygame.draw.arc()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.arc) (`(0, 0, 500, 350)`), when the start and end angle for the arc is calculated.
As mention in the comments you've to use `math.atan2` rather than `math.atan` to get angles in the range [`-pi`,  `pi`]. In pygame, the y axis points downwards, so the y component of the direction vector has to be inverted

```py
def angle(A, B, aspectRatio):
    x = B[0] - A[0]
    y = B[1] - A[1]
    angle = math.atan2(-y, x / aspectRatio)
    return angle

a1 = angle((250, 175), (75, 300), 500/350)
a2 = angle((250, 175),(400, 315), 500/350)

pygame.draw.arc(gameDisplay, WHITE, (0, 0, 500, 350), a1, a2)
```

[image]